# sas remote submit error

Tags: sas, remote-server

```
%let srv=myservername;
%let cntsrv=&srv 7541;
options comamid=tcp remote=cntsrv;
signon password=_prompt_;
run; 

    rsubmit "server_name-directory_path";
    data a;
    set b;
    run;
    endrsubmit;
```

I'm trying to access some data on the Linux server and bring it to my work directory using windows sas.
But I'm getting an error message

rsubmit "xxx-xxx.xxx.census.gov/hspb/ahs/indevlp/n2015/wgt/proddata";
WARNING: Connection to CNTSRV already exists. SCRIPT/SASCMD/SWAIT/TBUFSIZE specification will be
         ignored.

Comment: I did please see the edited question above.

Answer (score 1):

Is server_name-directory_path the path to your data? The `rsubmit;` must be to the `remote=` specified servername. If you have only signed on to one server, you can actually just leave out the server name;

```
rsubmit /*optional:*/ myservername;
    libname data "/hspb/ahs/indevlp/n2015/wgt/proddata";
    data a;
    set data.b;
    run;
endrsubmit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before **rsubmit** you need to describe your connection details and do **sign on** first.